# Отправка email сообщений используя templated_mail в Django

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework

При попытке отправки сообщения при помощи класса `from templated_mail.mail import BaseEmailMessage` в почтовом менеджере яндекса не отображается html_body.

Код, который используется для отправки сообщения:

```py
context = {'test': 'test_1'}

mail = BaseEmailMessage(context=context, template_name='email/test.html')
mail.send(to=[email])
```